# Unity Addressables - do all editor instances need a local copy?

Tags: unity, addressable

I'm able to get Unity addressables to load in editor 1 ("project 1"), where it is both generating  the .json/hash/bin and loading the prefab asset into scene. This is then placed on AWS (and the link has been tested to download in browser  `https://bucket.amazonaws.com/[BuildTarget]`).

However, in editor 2 ("project 2"), after setting up the remote_load to be the link above, the prefab does not load.

Maybe I am misunderstanding how this works - does "project 2" also need a local copy of the prefab, or can that itself load from the server?

Comment: So far as I'm aware, addressables are for dynamically loading assets in a *built game executable* not for loading remote files in the Editor application.

Comment: well i am able to load in editor the addressable in the generating project. just not in the editor on the other computer...