# Load Material from file path or parse .mat file to Material - Unity

Tags: unity, materials, path

Is it possible to load a material from a file path? Or, otherwise parse a .mat file saved on disk to a Material usable at runtime?

I had naively thought it would be possible to assign the bytes from a .mat file, as read by `File.ReadAllBytes` to a `Material` object, but that does not seem to work.

Comment: Loading assets from files at runtime is what [asset bundles](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/AssetBundlesIntro.html) used to be for and which you should now do with [addressables](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.addressables@1.16/manual/index.html). Unfortunately asset bundles are deprecated and I don't have enough experience with addressables to feel confident to write a proper answer.

Comment: However, this seems kind of like an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/) to me. Can you tell us more about why you want to load a material at runtime from a path and not just import it into your project and assign it in the Unity editor?

Comment: @Philipp think millions of materials already on a server etc

Comment: can't get addressable to work with assets from an external project, for other projects to use, unfortunately https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/186472/unity-addressables-do-all-editor-instances-need-a-local-copy?noredirect=1#comment336197_186472

Comment: Why would you load *millions* of materials from a server? Are you talking about user-generated content? How much do you really want the users to be able to customize?

Comment: not millions but just a large number. basically creating a workaround since Addressables and asset bundles don't seem to work

Comment: You might receive much more useful answers if you would tell us why exactly you want to do this and what you are trying to accomplish.